# Conditional assignment of value - is ifelse() the best when condition and intended return value don't have same features? [R]

Tags: r, if-statement, variable-assignment

I want to conditionally assign a value to a variable. For example, I want to create an `alphabet` variable and assign to it `letters` if a certain letter is lowercase, or assign to it `LETTERS` if a certain letter is uppercase.

The first thought was to use `<-` and `ifelse()`. However, this is not working in my case:

```
> alphabet <- ifelse("B" %in% letters, letters, LETTERS)
> alphabet
[1] "A"
```

In fact I saw that, with reference to `ifelse(test, yes, no)`, the function description says: "`ifelse` returns a value with the same shape as `test` which is filled with elements selected from either `yes` or `no` [...]". In the Value section, it specifies a bit more: "A vector of the **same length and attributes** (including dimensions and "`class`") as `test` and data values from the values of `yes` or `no`. [...]".

Ok - I realised that I can use `assign()` instead of `<-` and the value is assigned correctly to the variable:

```
> ifelse("B" %in% letters, assign("alphabet", letters), assign("alphabet", LETTERS))
[1] "A"
> alphabet
 [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J" "K" "L" "M" "N" "O" "P" "Q" "R" "S" "T" "U" "V" "W" "X" "Y" "Z"
```

However, as per the output above, `ifelse()` still returns the first character from the chosen set of letters.

I am not happy with this, because...

1. ... the fact that my code is returning something that I don't need, and...
2. ... the fact that `ifelse()` wouldn't actually even work with `<-` ...

make me wonder whether there is a better way to do this.

Is there a preferred / more efficient / better-etiquette or in any way more appropriate option to assign a value conditionally as in this case, or should I just ignore what is bothering me?

Comment: I guess you need to reverse i.e. `letters %in% "B"` beacause all the arguments should have the same length.  Also, `letters` are all lowercase values.  So, your logic should be with `LETTERS %in% 'B'`

Comment: If you are using different length i.e. 'B' %in% letters, better option is `if/else` i.e. `alphabet <- if('B' %in% letters) letters else LETTERS`

Comment: @akrun Perhaps I wasn't clear: I want to check whether a certain letter is lowercase or uppercase. If lowercase, I want to create `alphabet` and assign `letters` to it; if uppercase, I instead want to assign `LETTERS` to it. This makes me indifferent to using `letters` or `LETTERS` in the condition. I updated the question making it clearer. Anyway, using `letters %in% "B"` with `<-` doesn't work because it gives me `[1] "A" "b" "C" [...]`, with a lowercase "b". Using `letters %in% B` with `assign()` works as it worked in my question, but it doesn't eliminate my point 1 in the question.

Comment: Have you tried the code I showed `alphabet <- if('B' %in% letters) letters else LETTERS`

Comment: @akrun I had seen your comment before you edited it. That does the job more neatly, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `if/else` instead of `ifelse`

```
alphabet <- if('B' %in% letters) letters else LETTERS
```